# Popuppanel stays open after validation

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a rich faces popuppanel that I want to keep open until all validation is done. For now I just have a required attribute on the address. If the address is missing and the Submit button is clicked the popuppanel should stay open until the address is entered which it does. However when the user enters an address the form sends the email as it should but the page stays open. I need the popuppanel to close when the required field is entered.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="addressModalPanel" header="Change Billing Address" modal="true" domElementAttachment="form" width="450" height="400">
            <h2>Submit Change of Billing Address</h2>
            <h:outputLabel value="Enter changes to your company's billing address in the fields below and then click Submit" /><br></br>             
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" >                      
                    <h:outputLabel value="Company Name: "/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.supplierName}" disabled="true" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Vendor Number: " />
                    <h:inputText value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.id}" disabled="true"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Address: " />
                    <h:inputText id="add1" value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.add1}" required="true" requiredMessage="Address is required" style="width:200px" />                                                
                    <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.add2}" style="width:200px" />
                    <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.add3}" style="width:200px" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="City: " />
                    <h:inputText id="city" value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.city}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="State: " />
                    <h:inputText id="state" value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.state}" style="width:50px" />                            
                    <h:outputLabel value="Zip: " />
                    <h:inputText id="zip" value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.zip}" style="width:50px" />                            
                    <h:outputLabel value="Country (If not US): " />
                    <h:inputText id="country" value="#{supplieraddress.supplierAddress.country}" style="width:50px" />                                                            

                    <a4j:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" actionListener="#{supplieraddress.billingAddressEmail()}" oncomplete="if(#{!empty add1}) #{rich:component('addressModalPanel')}.hide()" >

                    </a4j:commandButton>   

                    <h:commandButton value="Close" >              
                        <rich:componentControl event="click" target="addressModalPanel" operation="hide" />             
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                        <rich:message for="add1" style="color:red"/>
                    </a4j:outputPanel>                       

                </h:panelGrid>                          


            </rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(#{!empty add1})` looks like a misuse of the `empty` operator; `empty` is to be applied to Collections only. What you should be using instead

```
<a4j:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" actionListener="#{supplieraddress.billingAddressEmail()}" oncomplete="if(!#{facesContext.validationFailed}) #{rich:component('addressModalPanel')}.hide()" >
```

Where `facesContext.validationFailed` is a convenience method that checks the validation status of the current JSF context